# Aurelia, call click function before route-href

Tags: javascript, aurelia

i have a seemingly simple problem that i want to solve, but for the life of me, i can't get it to work.
I have a function `setStatus()` that i want to be called before routing to another page.

`test1.js`

```
export class Test1{

  setStatus() {
    this.statusId = 1
  }
}
```

`test1.hmtl`

```
<template>
  <a route-href="route:test2" click.delegate="setStatus()">  <!-- search-href="model.bind: searchModel"> -->
    <h3 class="tsd-dashboard-block__title">${'overdue' & t}</h3>
    <span class="tsd-dashboard-block__count">${count}</span>
  </a>
</template>
```

The problem is it just routes directly to test2 and it wont call the `setStatus()` function in test1.

I also tried using `click.trigger` too but nothing.
Can anyone point out what im doing wrong here or do i need to use some special aurelia routing events? Thanks

P.S i also followed the example in this [link](https://elanderson.net/2017/01/aurelia-router-links-click-delegate-routing-parameters/)

Comment: Can you try to use `click.capture=yourMethod()`. Also remember to return true ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I'm facing the same problem now and even tried the same link you posted here... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never mixed events like that, but I've solved similar problems by using the Router programmatically.

Basically you can in your setStatus()

```
setStatus() {
  this.statusId = 0;
  this.router.navigateToRoute('route:test2');
}
```

To make this work you need to inject the Router in the constructor.

```
@inject(Router)
export class Test1 {
  constructor(router) {
    this.router = router;
  }

  ...
  setStatus() { ... }
  ...

}
```

Edit: I'd recommend renaming the `setStatus` method to something more explicit :)

Edit2: As @PW Kad mentions, this shouldn't be a link in terms of UX. This is more of an action with the side effect of a navigation  and a `<button>` will be a better choice of HTML Element.

Comment: This works but I wouldn't suggest it for user experience reasons - an anchor without an href is not navigable the same way (such as right click open in new window)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to call a function before the anchor is pressed you could probably do it on mousedown so it gets fired earlier than the click handler which is called before the handler is.  Something like `mousedown.trigger="myMethod()"` should work. Be sure to return true from myMethod() or it will not navigate as expected.

Comment: For some reason, it only calls the function but it does not route after the function is finished :(

Comment: Oh just return true from your method then.

Comment: Hmm it still wouldn't navigate. It doesn't show any error either. It just finish the function and stopped...
I have even tried using `mouseenter.trigger` but it still wouldnt navigate after.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a route-href="route:test2" click.delegate="setStatus()">
```

I think you are missing a "